# How to fix "Django_Jalali" utcoffset(dt) in django models?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using django_jalali as Persian calendar into my Django project and I wanted to add auto_now_add and auto_add for created_at and updated_at variables that hold time.
When I add a post from Django admin it will apply correctly with no problem but when I want to update the post it will crash by `utcoffset(dt) argument must be a datetime instance or None, not datetime` error

I tried to remove all and use default argument in jmodels of `django_jalali` but it will crash the same as above

Here it is my Post model:

```py
from django_jalali.db import models as jmodels

created_at = jmodels.jDateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = jmodels.jDateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I should tell again that it works first time fine and hold the date correctly but when I save the post again it will crash by the bellow error

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1/admin/post/post/6/change/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: utcoffset(dt) argument must be a datetime instance or None, not datetime
Exception Location: \env\lib\site-packages\jdatetime\__init__.py in utcoffset, line 1220
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed by adding an extra argument to variables here is the code:

```py
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem in [Jdatetime](https://github.com/slashmili/python-jalali) library which is used by `django-jalali` as a dependency.
Upgrade the `Jdatetime` package will fix it.